# How does Bash auto completion work?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I can understand that bash auto completion works for standard utilities. But how does it do auto completion for custom programs like Oracle SQL loader?

In the following command if you Tab after `control=` then it autocompletes to the control file name:

```
sqlldr kshitiz/oracle@XE control=data.ctl data=data.csv bad=data.bad log=data.log
```

How does it know it has to fill in the control file at that point and not some other file?

Comment: Completion of parameters are done with functions. Most of them are set up in `/etc/bash_completion.d`. See also `/etc/bash_completion` and take a look at the output of `set`, how much you environment has grown.

Comment: @ott What should I be looking for in that location? I unable to see anything related to sqlldr. All I have is: `gdbus-bash-completion.sh`  `gvfs-bash-completion.sh`  `pk-completion.bash`  `yum.bash`. The output of `set` is just as uninteresting.

Comment: It could also be done in some script from `/etc/profile.d`. Or maybe your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` was modified.

Comment: How are these functions different from normal functions. And how'd I go about defining my own to provide auto complete for a custom script? Could you point in the right direction?

Comment: Btw, I used grep to text search my `~` and `/etc` for `sqlldr` and didn't find anything interesting. I wonder where oracle placed those functions.

Comment: If you type `complete -p sqlldr`, bash will tell you what function (and other flags) are configured for the completion of that command.

Comment: Strange. Bash tells me that nothing is configured. `bash: complete: sqlldr: no completion specification`

Comment: @KshitizSharma, `bash-completion` loads completions dynamically since [`1.90`](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/tree/CHANGES#n316). Try: `sqlldr<space><tab><enter>`. Then type `complete -p sqlldr`.

Comment: Also try `complete -pD`. This command prints existing completion specification for commands without any specific completion defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash's [programmable completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) works by parsing the command line and figuring out what is being completed:

1. Some contexts are treated specially, e.g. the first word in a command is completed as a command name, what follows a `$` is completed as a variable name, etc.
2. Outside of these contexts, bash attempts to complete the argument of a command, and the settings for command or failing that (which is usually the case) for the basename of the command are applied.

For example, after `sqllTab`, bash completes command names that start with `sqll`. After `sqlldr $aTab`, bash completes variable names that start with `a`. After `sqlldr Tab`, bash applies the completion rules for the command `sqlldr`. Completion rules can specify a category (user, variable, files, etc.), a wildcard pattern for file names, or a function or code snippet to execute.

Completion rules are defined by the [`complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-complete) builtin. Bash doesn't keep track of when the `complete` builtin was called or what script (if any) it was in. Most distributions ship the [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package, which provides a series of rules for common commands. This takes the form of a series of script files that contain calls to `complete`, with a script that must be read from `.bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc` if implemented) to load all of these scripts: typically `. /etc/bash_completion` is needed to activate programmable completion and load the available scripts.

The standard package does not include support for `sqlldr`. If you have such support, it must be coming from a different source. This source might have dropped a file in a directory like `/etc/bash_completion.d` or might have come with instructions to include some code in your `.bashrc`. You can use `complete -p sqlldr` to see the current rules for `sqlldr`; as mentioned before, this won't tell you where those rules were loaded from.

Tcsh, zsh and fish have somewhat similar mechanisms (everybody got their inspiration from tcsh) but different builtins, syntaxes and capabilities.

Comment: yes, you can't locate where `complete` was called. But you can find the source file name and line number where the completion function is defined. `complete -p sudo # outputs complete -F _sudo sudo`, `shopt -s extdebug`, `declare -F _sudo # outputs _sudo 3 /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo`. (But see my [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205360/how-does-bash-auto-completion-work#comment360892_205360) about dynamically completions loading and `complete -p`).

Comment: `and the settings for the basename of the command are applied`. No. You can have a different compspecs for `date` and `/bin/date`. Reference [says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion): If the command word is a full pathname, a compspec for the full pathname is searched for first. If no compspec is found for the full pathname, an attempt is made to find a compspec for the portion following the final slash