# Making the first word I type on terminal of different color from the others

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

New here. I was trying to make the first word I type on the terminal of a different color from the others. I have looked into the `.bashrc` file and `/etc/inputrc` files. I know that I can make use of the GNU `readline` library to achieve what I want, because it helps in processing the text while the text is being typed, as suggested in the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205360/how-does-bash-auto-completion-work). I however, do not wish to mess with the `/etc/inputrc` and `.bashrc` files without being sure it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to highlight the command, but you can write e.g. `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH some -thing -or other`... what would your "first word" be?