# How does Bash/Zsh identify the relevant command during completion?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, autocomplete

When I start typing something into an interactive login shell (zsh or bash) and click *tab*, the shell offers me autocomplete suggestions.

I broadly understand how completion specs are defined. For reference it's outlined here:

- Bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion
- Zsh: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html

What I don't understand is how bash/zsh identify which command to complete on when a user presses tab i.e. if I do `ls [tab]`, how does bash/zsh identify `ls`. Put differently, how do bash/zsh know to generate completions using the `ls` completion spec.

Some more examples with more complicated parsing which Bash/Zsh still get right:

- `ls [tab]`  -> completes on `ls`
- `echo $( echo $(ls [tab]`  -> completes on `ls`
- `echo hi; git a[tab]`  -> completes on `git`
- `echo 'cd [tab]`  -> does NOT complete on `cd`
- `echo "$(ls [tab]`  -> completes on `ls`
- `echo $( echo hi | ls [tab]`  -> completes on `ls`
  (I know `ls` doesn't take stdin but this example still illustrates bash/zsh's parsing abilities)

I am presuming bash/zsh are using some sort of parser. However, it's not a normal parser. It completes without a properly structured command. It is aware that something is in quotes or a shell expansion, even if they are not closed.

What function is bash/zsh running to "identify" the relevant command or determine whether or not there is a command to complete on at all?

Comment: the shells have a parser, and obviously know their own syntax, so it's normal that they are able to determine that they are completing on a certain command context, or that the command ended on a string context. It's easier to confuse them when completing in the middle of a command. Try something like `echo $(ls [TAB])`

Comment: Thanks @Ángel - I am sure it's easier to confuse them in the middle of a command. The thing is, it's not confusing them! Considering everything is open source, I would love to find the source code for the parser...

Comment: Files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` and `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` are pretty self-explanatory.

1. You define a completion function via:

`complete -F _function_name application_name`

i.e.

`complete -F _ls ls`

2. Then you define function _function_name which expands values.

Comment: Shells keep a cache of all the names of the executables in the directories in `$PATH`. This is used for completion. See the `rehash` builtin in `man bash`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov This is helpful for defining the completion function and @waltinator this is helpful for finding the executable. But it doesn't answer my question: how does does bash know what completion executable to use? e.g. a user inputs `ls [tab]` how does bash know to find the `_ls` completion function as opposed to `_cd` or `_git`.

Comment: I would assume that the shell uses a simple left to right parser (I am not hot on the terminology). E.g put cursor after `ls` in `echo $(ls ( ) )` and press tab, it auto completes even when the code to the right is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What function is bash/zsh running to "identify" the relevant command or determine whether or not there is a command to complete on at all?

When you press `tab`, readline executes the `complete` function.

You can override this in `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\t": complete
```

`complete` is defined in `lib/readline/funmap.c` as:

```
static const FUNMAP default_funmap[] = {
[..]
{ "complete", rl_complete },
```

`rl_complete` can be found in `lib/readline/complete.c` ([browse source](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/lib/readline/complete.c#L421)):

```
/* Complete the word at or before point.  You have supplied the function
   that does the initial simple matching selection algorithm (see
   rl_completion_matches ()).  The default is to do filename completion. */
int
rl_complete (int ignore, int invoking_key)
{
..
```

This is the starting point. It breaks apart the words, checks which completions are registered and then looks for the relevant completions.

zsh will probably have a similar implementation.

There is also a good explanation of the process [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205409/46158).